# how to set default selection in radio button - Active form yii

Tags: php, yii, radio-button

Here i need to add default selection in radio button(checked).

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'login-form']); ?>    
<?= $form->field($model, 'email') ?>
<?php if(!empty($usernames)){ 
    echo '<label>Select Any Username To Which You Want To Login</label><div class="all_username">';
    foreach ($usernames as $key => $value) { ?>
        <?= $form->field($model, 'username[]')->radio(['value' => $value['username'], 'id' => ''])->label($value['username']) ?>
    <?php } ?>
    </div>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'password')->passwordInput() ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: why don't you use a radioList?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use following method where 1 is your selected ID.

```
$form->radioButtonList($model,'1', $usernames, array('separator'=>"" ));
```

Comment: there is no other option to select default in existing code?

Comment: can you please tell me which Yii version you are using?

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use something like this:

```
foreach ($usernames as $key => $value) { 
    if(/*somecondition*/){
        $model->username = $value['username'];
    }?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'username[]')->radio(['value' => $value['username'], 'id' => ''])->label($value['username']) ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Only by assigning the `$model->username` a default value you can choose which radio will be selected.

Comment: i have added in my code, but there is no default selection after adding this

Comment: What condition did you use?

Comment: I mean, how exactly did you implement this?

Comment: foreach ($usernames as $key => $value) { 
      if($key == 0)
       $model->username = $value['username'];?>
                        <?= $form->field($model, 'username[]')->radio(['value' => $value['username'], 'id' => ''])->label($value['username']) ?>
                    <?php } ?>